# Bootstrap + d3.js stacking graphs

Tags: javascript, html, d3.js

I have two large graphs (page width) that I want to display on a webpage.

The graphs have been made responsive.

Currently, the graphs are displayed on top of eachother. My guess is that, due to the resizing of the graphs using JavaScript, the div's are not being resized or are in effect height 0 (which happens if I remove `position: absolute` from the CSS.

The JavaScript code for both graphs is identical. The only thing I have changed is change the variable name of the chart, and changed the `id` of the div in which to inject the graph.

I have tried playing around with `position` in CSS, using `float` and all the regular things one finds.

I am really out of ideas. Any great help is greatly appreciated.

Ps: I tried putting this into a Codepen but couldn't get it to work. A live example of the source can be found at http://call-cc.be:5000/

#### CSS

```
body {
    padding-top: 50px;
    background-color: #fefefe;
}

/*Graphs*/

.axis path,
.axis line {
    fill: none;
    stroke: #000000;
    shape-rendering: crispEdges;
}

.axis text {
    fill: #555;
}

.line {
    fill: none;
    stroke: #65a2ef;
    stroke-width: 1.5px;
}

#humidity, #temperature {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
}
```

#### Humidity graph javascript

```
var margin = 50,
    width = parseInt(d3.select("#humidity").style("width")) - margin * 2,
    height = parseInt(d3.select("#humidity").style("height")) - margin * 2;

var xScale = d3.time.scale()
    .range([0, width]);

var yScale = d3.scale.linear()
    .range([height, 0]);

var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(xScale)
    .orient("bottom");

var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(yScale)
    .orient("left");

var line = d3.svg.line()
    .interpolate("basis")
    .x(function (d) {
        return xScale(d.date);
    })
    .y(function (d) {
        return yScale(d.close);
    });

var humidityChart = d3.select("#humidity").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width + margin * 2)
    .attr("height", height + margin * 2)
    .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin + "," + margin + ")");

d3.csv("/push/humidity", function (error, data) {
    data.forEach(function (d) {
        var dt = new Date();
        dt.setUTCSeconds(parseInt(d.timestamp));
        d.date = dt;
        d.close = parseFloat(d.value);
    });

    xScale.domain(d3.extent(data, function (d) {
        return d.date;
    }));
    console.log(d3.extent(data, function (d) {
        return d.date;
    }));
    yScale.domain(d3.extent(data, function (d) {
        return d.close;
    }));

    humidityChart.append("g")
        .attr("class", "x axis")
        .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
        .call(xAxis);

    humidityChart.append("g")
        .attr("class", "y axis")
        .call(yAxis)
        .append("text")
        .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
        .attr("y", 6)
        .attr("dy", ".71em")
        .style("text-anchor", "end")
        .text("Temperature (Celcius)");

    humidityChart.append("path")
        .datum(data)
        .attr("class", "line")
        .attr("d", line);


    function resize() {
        console.log('humidity resizing');

        //var width = d3.select("#humidity").getBoundingClientRect().width;
        var width = parseInt(d3.select("#humidity").style("width")) - margin * 2;
        var height = parseInt(d3.select("#humidity").style("height")) - margin * 2;

        xScale.range([0, width]).nice();
        yScale.range([height, 0]).nice();

        yAxis.ticks(Math.max(height / 50, 2));
        xAxis.ticks(Math.max(width / 100, 2));

        humidityChart.select('.x.axis')
            .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
            .call(xAxis);

        humidityChart.select('.y.axis')
            .call(yAxis);

        humidityChart.selectAll('.line')
            .attr("d", line);
    }

    window.addEventListener('resize', resize);

    resize();
});
```

#### Temperature graph javascript

```
var margin = 50,
    width = parseInt(d3.select("#temperature").style("width")) - margin * 2,
    height = parseInt(d3.select("#temperature").style("height")) - margin * 2;

var xScale = d3.time.scale()
    .range([0, width]);

var yScale = d3.scale.linear()
    .range([height, 0]);

var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(xScale)
    .orient("bottom");

var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(yScale)
    .orient("left");

var line = d3.svg.line()
    .interpolate("basis")
    .x(function (d) {
        return xScale(d.date);
    })
    .y(function (d) {
        return yScale(d.close);
    });

var temperatureChart = d3.select("#temperature").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width + margin * 2)
    .attr("height", height + margin * 2)
    .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin + "," + margin + ")");

d3.csv("/push/temperature", function (error, data) {
    data.forEach(function (d) {
        var dt = new Date();
        dt.setUTCSeconds(parseInt(d.timestamp));
        d.date = dt;
        d.close = parseFloat(d.value);
    });

    xScale.domain(d3.extent(data, function (d) {
        return d.date;
    }));
    console.log(d3.extent(data, function (d) {
        return d.date;
    }));
    yScale.domain(d3.extent(data, function (d) {
        return d.close;
    }));

    temperatureChart.append("g")
        .attr("class", "x axis")
        .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
        .call(xAxis);

    temperatureChart.append("g")
        .attr("class", "y axis")
        .call(yAxis)
        .append("text")
        .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
        .attr("y", 6)
        .attr("dy", ".71em")
        .style("text-anchor", "end")
        .text("Temperature (Celcius)");

    temperatureChart.append("path")
        .datum(data)
        .attr("class", "line")
        .attr("d", line);


    function resize() {

        console.log('temperature resizing');

        //var width = d3.select("#temperature").getBoundingClientRect().width;
        var width = parseInt(d3.select("#temperature").style("width")) - margin * 2;
        var height = parseInt(d3.select("#temperature").style("height")) - margin * 2;

        xScale.range([0, width]).nice();
        yScale.range([height, 0]).nice();

        yAxis.ticks(Math.max(height / 50, 2));
        xAxis.ticks(Math.max(width / 100, 2));

        temperatureChart.select('.x.axis')
            .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
            .call(xAxis);

        temperatureChart.select('.y.axis')
            .call(yAxis);

        temperatureChart.selectAll('.line')
            .attr("d", line);
    }

    d3.select(window).on('resize', resize);

    resize();
});
```

#### HTML

The problematic code is at the bottom. Two `div`s are defined: one with id `temperature` and one with id `humidity`.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <!-- The above 3 meta tags *must* come first in the head; any other head content must come *after* these tags -->
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">
    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="/img/favicon.png"/>
    <title>Pok Pok</title>

    <!-- bower:css -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/lib/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/lib/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css" />
    <!-- endbower -->

    <!-- bower:js -->
    <script src="/lib/jquery/dist/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="/lib/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
    <!-- endbower -->

    <!-- inject:css -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/starter-template.css">
    <!-- endinject -->

    <!-- inject:js -->
    <script src="/js/ie-emulation-modes-warning.js"></script>
    <script src="/js/ie10-viewport-bug-workaround.js"></script>
    <!-- endinject -->


    <!-- HTML5 shim and Respond.js for IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
    <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.2/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
</head>

<body>
<style>


</style>
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar"
                    aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
                <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Pok Pok</a>
        </div>
        <div id="navbar" class="collapse navbar-collapse">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <% for(var i = 0; i < nav.length; i++) { %>
                <li><a href="<%= nav[i].link %>"><%= nav[i].text %></a></li>
                <% } %>
            </ul>
        </div><!--/.nav-collapse -->
    </div>
</nav>



<!--The container-->
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12" id="humidity">

    </div>
</div>

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12" id="temperature">

    </div>
</div>
</body>

<!-- load the d3.js library -->
<script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
<script src="/graphs/humidity.js"></script>
<script src="/graphs/temperature.js"></script>

</html>
```

Comment: Can you share the code for temperature? Inspecting the DOM, I can't see the div for humidity (id="humidity").

Comment: Why are both divs set at posición absolute? Try to remove that css line

Comment: @torresomar: When I remove that CSS line the div's are only 20px high. Even after a resize. Gerado Furtado: The div is in the last file I have posted here. And the code for temperature graph has been added. However, it is exactly the same, except "#humidity" replaced with "#temperature" and "humidityChart" with "temperatureChart".

Comment: Currently I have fixed it by setting the height of the diagram in the javascript in terms of the width: `height = (width / 16) * 9 ;`

Comment: Could it be a problem that you have `var xScale`, `var yScale`, `var xAxis`, and `var yAxis` all defined twice? I notice that resizing causes the axes to be identical. Perhaps name these uniquely for each graph.

Comment: did you solve it? if so pls share the answer